# Uploading plugin assembly to MS CRM Online programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to upload new version of plugin assembly containing CRM plugins to MS CRM Online instance by using my custom application, not `PluginRegistrationTool`.

Approach is really straightforward:

```
var plugin = new Entity("pluginassembly")
{
    Id = PluginId // correct GUID of the plugin assembly stored in CRM
};

plugin["content"] = Convert.ToBase64String(ReadBinaryFile(filename));

Service.Update(plugin);
```

The code works fine when I'm testing with CRM on-premises. However, when I point `Service` to MS CRM online, the result is not successful.

The assembly is uploaded, but when I'm trying to execute step to which it's assigned, CRM fires `SecurityException`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #E824CF49Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #E824CF49</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-06-24T07:57:27.5491666Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

I can understand, that CRM Online probably performs additional checks. But I cannot understand what exactly it checks and why assembly uploaded with `PluginRegistrationTool` passes this checks, and uploaded directly — fails that checks.

Have anyone experienced already issues like this? Maybe someone could help answer without reverse engineering `PluginRegistrationTool`?

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Comment: Looking up the error code (0x80040216), it just tells me the exception is "Unexpected". Are you able to register the same assembly on premise in the sandbox? Do you have other plugins installed Online?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I just tried the same thing (register plugin in On-Prem environment in sandbox and update it via my code) — the result is the same as for CRM Online — success updating and unexpected security error while executing.

Comment: Does your plugin reference external libraries or does it have other dependencies?  The `SecurityException` hints to a security compromising construct in your plugin. You could add tracelines just before calls to your methods. The JiT-compiler hits security exceptions when compiling the method it needs to execute for the first time.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen that helped! Thanks! I wrote detailed explanation in answer below. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HenkvanBoeijen's comment gave me a clue, that actually helped.

My plugin uses external libraries, and they are packaged with the main code using `ILMerge` tool. But. It was an error during merging process. Resulting file was captured by my code *BEFORE* it was signed by `ILMerge`. Thus, file itself was OK, but since it's not signed with the strong name, it failed in `Isolated` mode and was ok in `Normal` mode.

So the solution was not to hurry up and let `ILMerge` complete it's job. After that everything worked fine.